# Lambda function is giving unexpected output

Tags: c++

I was going through lambda functions on https://shaharmike.com/cpp/lambdas-and-functions/ and found below code.

```
int i = 0;
auto x = [i]() mutable { cout << ++i << endl; };
x();
cout << i << endl;
auto y = x;
x();
y();
```

**Output:**

```
1
0
2
2
```

Unable to understand why last 2 statements are getting printed as 2 and 2. Even though 'i' is mutable, it will not effect i value outside lamda function. so, x() and y() should print 1 and 1. Can any one please explain why it is printing 2 and 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` has a copy of `i`.  I will call it `x.i`.

```
x(); -- prints ++x.i, aka 1
cout << i; -- prints i, aka 0
auto y = x; -- copies x into y.  x.i is 1, y.i is also 1.
x(); -- prints ++x.i, aka 2
y(); -- prints ++y.i, aka 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `i` is saved as a field of the functor generated by the lambda function, so when you copy it, the field is copied as well with the value `1`. Then calling the functor increments each object's `i` field and displays that value, so you get `2` and `2`.